# POST error 500 (Internal Server Error) - JSON syntax error

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, json, post

I have an AngularJS 1.5 app with a form that posts data to a db. In the form there is a drop down select. The problem is, some options in the drop down POST successfully while others encounter a POST error saying

```
POST http://localhost/myURL 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

and beneath it...

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at Object.qc [as fromJson] (angular.js:1285)
    at apiError (postFormCtrl.js:957)
    at AjaxServices.js:37
    at angular.js:11029
    at angular.js:15616
    at m.$eval (angular.js:16884)
    at m.$digest (angular.js:16700)
    at m.$apply (angular.js:16992)
    at g (angular.js:11313)
```

What could be causing some items from the same form to POST successfully and others to encounter this error? I've double checked the code for missing commas, brackets etc... there's none.

I've inspected the output on browsers, the response headers for successful posts have

`Content-Type:application/json`  in the response headers while failed POSTs have

`Content-Type:text/html` in the response headers. Could this be the issue?

And if it is, how do I prevent it because I don't have a single setting in the application that sets the content-type as text/html.

Additionally, I know the problem cannot be in the ajax post function because the entire application utilizes the same ajax post function and they work well.

**MORE INFO**

This is an example of an item in the drop down select:

```
                <div class="row" ng-if="isStudentActivity">
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <label for="activity">Select an activity:</label>
                        <div>
                            <ui-select ng-model="theactivity.selected" theme="select2" class="form-control" name="activity" required>
                              <ui-select-match placeholder="Select or search an activity...">
                                <span>{{$select.selected.activity}}</span>
                              </ui-select-match>
                              <ui-select-choices repeat="item in activities | filter: $select.search">
                                <span ng-bind-html="item.activity | highlight: $select.search"></span>
                              </ui-select-choices>
                            </ui-select>
                            <p ng-show="dataFilterForm.activity.$invalid && (!dataFilterForm.activity.$pristine || dataFilterForm.$submitted)" class="help-block"><i class="fa fa-exclamation-triangle"></i> You must choose an activity.</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

And this is the ajax function used by all the POSTs in the application

```
       this.AjaxPost2 = function (data, route, successFunction, errorFunction, extras) 
       {
        $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: route,
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
            data: data
        }).success(function (response, status, headers, config) {
            successFunction(response, status, extras);
        }).error(function (response) {
            errorFunction(response);
        });

    }
```

And the function is called using

```
this.addCommunication = function (request, successFunction, errorFunction, params) {
        ajaxService.AjaxPost2(request, path + "/addCommunication", successFunction, errorFunction, params);
    };
```

Comment: What are you posting? JSON object, string, anything else?

Comment: You should show some code, otherwise we can only guess.

Comment: you have an error in your backend (PHP?) check how you are processing your data

Comment: @AlekseySolovey are you sure? What if he is posting JSON object and the server expects string?

Comment: According to the data I inspect, it posts JSON objects

Comment: The options, which on select this error must be having quotes or ":" which is being added in JSON, so please check that

Comment: @Clint_A try stringify before posting the object! `JSON.stringify(OBJECT)` or setting content-type to `text/plain`

Comment: Can you show us a sample response from the server?

Comment: @RahulJain I've checked the code for such errors, I haven't found anything yet. I've edited the question to include some code

Comment: @Clint_A Since you said only some of the options, on selecting, give error and that too, JSON Parse error. So it should be problem with the values those dropdown options contain which is being added in json data. If other options are working fine, then there should be no problem in code, I guess.

Comment: @chrisv that could be tricky as the entire application uses the same ajax function and everything works save for two drop down items in one form. However let me try it out. I've edited the question to include some code.

Comment: @RahulJain the thing is, on a failed post, when I inspect it, I can see the object's data that failed to post and everything looks fine.

Comment: @RahulJain This is an example object that failed to POST  `{
"user_id":1,
"post":{
"audience_id":7,
"com_type_id":1,
"send_method":"sms",
"title":"test",
"post_status_id":1,
"send_as_email":"f",
"send_as_sms":"t",
"message_from":38,
"body":"test"
}
}`

Comment: @Clint_A Hope you have fixed it yet. What was the problem?

Comment: Yes, it was fixed. Weird enough - the problem was from another part of the code unrelated to this one. It was a bug in a nested if statement higher up in the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A very late answer but I've come to learn that such errors are almost always due to to an error in the `api` itself. Syntax errors **mostly**. The front end is expecting a `json` to be returned but the api experienced hitches so it never ran or returned something else.

A quick way to solve this is to run the api in a REST client like postman or insomnia, see what's returned and make the necessary fixes.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the error html is not generated by your code but host (like IIS). It could be a better practice to create your error response with json data. 
Anyway, you can handle ok and error response separately in angularJs.

`$http.post` returns a promise object, which can be used like

```
$http.post(url, data)
.then(function(response){
   //handle normal result data here 
})
.catch(function(response){
  //handle error case here 
})
```

Comment: There are already success and error responses in the code. I've edited the question to include some code

Comment: @Clint_A, just see your update, maybe you can check if you are parsing html as json in errorFunction

Answer (score 0):

Its not fully completed question. You have to mention the data that you trying to parse and its response.

You are getting 500 error its seems you are getting error from server.
it means your back-end code making error.

Also please check your parsing dataType.

I think you have to mention `responseType` to `"json"`.

```
   this.AjaxPost2 = function (data, route, successFunction, errorFunction, extras) 
   {
    $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: route,
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
        data: data,
       responseType: 'json',
    }).success(function (response, status, headers, config) {
        successFunction(response, status, extras);
    }).error(function (response) {
        errorFunction(response);
    });

}
```

You have to mention which data you are parsing.